# Unable to load Officejs add-in from App store

Tags: excel, office-js, office-addins, excel-addins, office-js-store

This error `**Add-in Error** We couldn't connect to the 'Office Store' catalog server for this add-in`. is shown when user tries to access the add-in.

[See image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mnDKA.png)

Steps to reproduce:

1. Open new excel file
2. Download the app from app-store.

Also tried removing the add-in and then re-adding it from the store but the same error persists.

Answer (score 0):

Office won't be able to connect to the add-ins catalog unless there's a live internet connection, so when you see this error message, start your browser and make sure you can bring up a page or two that you haven't visited before. Or better yet, try to navigate to the add-in's web page. You can also try using any troubleshooting tools like Fiddler to see what happens under the hood.

This may be for a variety of reasons:

- No internet connection
- Blocked by firewall
- Access disabled by a security policy
- Add-in installation disabled by an administrator for Office applications